# mysql - If not match rows then store in new field

Tags: mysql, left-join

The given query works fine, But i want some modification. In 3rd line i have

> LEFT JOIN `tbl_emp` ON `inventory`.`itemGiven` = `tbl_emp`.`Sname`

This is filter the output if match. 
But problem is, all the `inventory`.`itemGiven`  is not present in `tbl_emp`.`Sname`. and i want, if not match then the result store in different field.

```
SELECT `inventory`.`ID` , `inventory`.`out_` , `inventory`.`userName` , date_format( `inventory`.`date` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS date, `department`.`id` , `tbl_emp`.`emp_id_number`
FROM `inventory`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_emp` ON `inventory`.`itemGiven` = `tbl_emp`.`Sname`
LEFT JOIN `department` ON `inventory`.`givenDept` = `department`.`dept`
WHERE `out_` >0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I know this is possible, please anybody help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want exactly? do you want to match with some other field if data won't get match in `inventory.itemGiven = tbl_emp.Sname`?

Comment: If this is not match then i want to get the `inventory.itemGiven` separately.

Comment: can you please elaborate how will you get that one?

Comment: In SELECT ...............  FROM.

The dot(.) place where i can get these. I already have `tbl_emp`.`emp_id_number` for this condition but when `inventory.itemGiven = tbl_emp.Sname` not match then the result is NULL. SO i want to select the `inventory.itemGiven` when not match.

Comment: Replace `tbl_emp.emp_id_number` with `IFNULL(tbl_emp.emp_id_number,inventory.itemGiven)` in select part

Comment: its perfect, But i got the problem with my `tbl_emp` table. Any way thanks.

Comment: Would appreciate if you will accept my answer if it's already worked for you.

Comment: What if an employee changes their name - or a department changes their's ? You appear to have some serious design flaws here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `tbl_emp.emp_id_number` with `IFNULL(tbl_emp.emp_id_number,inventory.itemGiven)` in select part

```
SELECT `inventory`.`ID` , `inventory`.`out_` , `inventory`.`userName` , date_format( `inventory`.`date` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS date, `department`.`id` , `tbl_emp`.`emp_id_number`
FROM `inventory`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_emp` ON `inventory`.`itemGiven` = `tbl_emp`.`Sname`
LEFT JOIN `department` ON `inventory`.`givenDept` = `department`.`dept`
WHERE `out_` >0
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated in Answer.